# How to get the same result with Lambda in java8

Tags: lambda, java-8

```
for (GroupEntity groupEntity : groups) {
        // find roles belongs to group
        Collection<RoleEntity> groupRoles = groupEntity.getRoles();
        for (RoleEntity roleEntity : groupRoles) {
            if (roleEntity.getType() == RoleType.MODULE) {
                ModuleEntity module = roleEntity.getModule();
                if (!modules.contains(module)) {
                    // prevent duplicate module
                    modules.add(module);
                }
            } else if (roleEntity.getType() == RoleType.OUTLINE) {
                OutlineEntity outline = roleEntity.getOutline();
                //prevent duplicate outline
                if (!outlines.contains(outline)) {
                    outlines.add(outline);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the same result with Lambda.And i tried But it ruturned `List<List<RoleEntity>>`.

```
    List<List<RoleEntity>> roles= groups.stream().map(g->g.getRoles().stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(RoleEntity::getId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream().filter(r->RoleType.MODULE.equals(r.getType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

i konw lambda is a amazing idea for coder.But learning it seems not so easy.Hope somebody can help me solve problems.Thanks! :XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `groupingBy`

```
    Map<RoleType, Set<Object>> roleTypeSetMap = groups.stream()
            .flatMap(g -> g.getRoles().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RoleEntity::getType, Collectors.mapping(r -> (r.getType() == RoleType.MODULE) ? r.getModule() : r.getOutline(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

if `ModuleEntity` and `OutlineEntity` have a common parent (Let's say `Entity`) we can change `Set<Object>` to `Set<Entity>`

Comment: `ModuleEntity` and `OutlineEntity` are different.They don't have a common parent.i want to know how to cast `Set<Object> ` to `Set<ModuleEntity> ` or `Set<T> `

Comment: This solution assumes that role type is either a module or an outline

Comment: @Misha true, OP needs to filter if other types are not required, or switch case to map different types